# Is it possible create bots for iMessage?

Tags: ios, swift, bots, imessage

I'm exploring possibilities of creating a Bot for iMessages. I went through the "Messages SDK" provided by Apple for iMessage extensions and didn't find any leads.

Android has Telephony(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony) which I could use as a starting point. But I couldn't find anything similar on iOS.

If anyone knows how I could achieve this, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iMessages is a closed platform, I don't think I have that possibility.

you can check
https://developer.apple.com/business-chat/

> **Business Chat**
>
> is a powerful new way for organizations to connect with customers directly from within Messages. Using Business Chat, your customers can get answers to questions, resolve issues and complete transactions on their iPhone, iPad, Mac and Apple Watch. Customers can find your business and start conversations from Safari, Maps, Search and Siri.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out Jared, an open-source iMessage chatbot which reads from the message database.
https://github.com/ZekeSnider/Jared

Comment: I was looking for a solution for iOS. But thanks for sharing this as well. This looks promising.

Comment: No problem, there's actually a bot called sue you can add to your group conversations as well, you can kind of see what they're capable of. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocTAFPCH_A0

Comment: I added it to a few group conversations (sue@robertism.com) and it's actually a really cool bot

Answer (score 2):

You could check out https://sendblue.co

Here is their documentation: https://docs.sendblue.co

I assume you can send and receive iMessages by simply hitting their endpoint with a post request, like so:

```js
const url = `https://api.sendblue.co/api/send-message` ;

axios.post(url, {
        number: '+19998887777',
        content: 'Hello world!',
        statusCallback: 'https://example.com/message-status/1234abcd',
    },
    headers: {
        "sb-api-key-id": << apiKey >> ,
        "sb-api-secret-key": << apiSecret >>
    },
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

You can receive iMessages by registering a webhook with them.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea! You could just add a phone number or an email to the chat that is connected to a bot script which would send messages directly from that phone number/email. I think that would work.

Comment: You're just restating the question